# sonicwall tz 210 bandwidth monitor

Tags: sonicwall, cacti, bandwidth-measuring

How can I monitor bandwidth usage on my SonicWall TZ210?

Some info:

```
Model:  TZ 210
Product Code:   ***
Serial Number:  ***
Authentication Code:    ***
Firmware Version:   SonicOS Enhanced 5.5.1.0-5o
Safemode Version:   Safemode 5.0.1.13
ROM Version:    SonicROM 5.0.2.11
```

The current way (Log > Request) is not sufficient as I want to export the data.
I also heard you can use a webapp(PHP) called cacti to visualize but I don't know how to set up the connection from SonicWall. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**For basic stat:**

You need to activate the SMNP in the SonicWall and use a tool like PRTG/MRTG. I does not know if cacti can. (I never used that one)

Please follow one of those KB to activate the SMNP. (depending on your OS version)

[Configuring SNMP in SonicOS Standard and Enhanced (SW5096)](https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw5096)

[Configuring SNMPv3 in SonicOS (5.9 & above) and (6.1 & above) (SW11183)](https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw11183)

The MIB can be a problem, so you may have to update it too. Like this KB show.

[SNMP Query for Bandwidth Statistics Fails (SW3038)](https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw3038)

**For advanced stat:**

From sonicwall you can buy the viewpoint feature.

ViewPoint Upgrade

> Upgrade Required.  SonicWALL ViewPoint is a software solution that
>   creates dynamic, Web-based reports of network activity. SonicWALL
>   ViewPoint generates both real-time and historical reports to provide a
>   complete view of all activity through your SonicWALL Internet Security
>   Appliance. With SonicWALL ViewPoint, you are able to monitor network
>   access, enhance network security and anticipate future bandwidth
>   needs.  SonicWALL ViewPoint  •Displays bandwidth use by IP address and
>   service.  •Identifies inappropriate Web use.  •Presents detailed
>   reports of attacks.  •Collects and aggregates system and network
>   errors.

**For advanced stat, but only for a short time:**

Please run wireshark with a port mirror from your lan cable of the sonicwall.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the links. The first one works but I only get total traffic metrics. I want to be able to see which IP has used/is using the most bandwidth. Thanks.

Comment: @chx101 You will have to buy the sonicwall feature for that then, will edit my answer

Comment: What feature? The ViewPoint?

Comment: yes, it's the one

Comment: Well. The SonicWALL was configured/setup by someone else I can't get in contact with right now and they happen to have the name and password for mysonicwall.com so I can't download the ViewPoint. The good thing is it's already registered and we have 3 licences I think. The port mirroring option is not supported. So I guess I have to wait for the guy.